# What is the difference between the "any" and "all" search options?

Tags: support, jobs, user-interface

So far as I can tell, not only do they do the exact same thing, but they don't actually do *anything* to the search criteria.

Using "any" with nothing in the "what" and "where" controls:
http://careers.stackoverflow.com/Jobs?searchTerm=&searchType=Any&location=&range=20

Using "all" with the same as above:
http://careers.stackoverflow.com/Jobs?searchTerm=&searchType=All&location=&range=20

Both searches currently give me 360 results (same as if I click "view all").

Should these controls be removed? Or are they planned to be implemented somehow?

Comment: Looking at the answers, I cannot believe I asked this question. LOL. Accepting an answer in t-minus 5 minutes...

Comment: Makes me wonder if your slider question is correct too..... :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hmm... looks like they're implemented properly with "any" being an "or" search, and "all" being an "and" search. Cases in point (yes, they have results):

`bar foo`, "any"
http://careers.stackoverflow.com/Jobs?searchTerm=bar+foo&searchType=Any&location=&range=60

`bar foo`, "all"
http://careers.stackoverflow.com/Jobs?searchTerm=bar+foo&searchType=All&location=&range=60

Comment: Yes, it applies to the terms in the search box

Answer (score 3):

"Any" means that you'll hit searches for any of those terms. For example, "any" with "ETL Engineer" gets me [a whole bunch of Engineering jobs](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/Jobs?searchTerm=ETL+Engineer&searchType=Any&location=&range=20) (and probably a bunch of ETL jobs, whatever those are, I didn't bother looking that far).

"All" means that you'll hit searches for all of those terms. "ETL Engineer" gives me the [two ETL Engineer jobs](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/Jobs?searchTerm=ETL+Engineer&searchType=All&location=&range=20).

Answer (score 2):

The What box takes multiple search terms.  Say you put `C# python` into the what box.  If you have "any" selected you'll get results containing C#, results containing python and results containing C# and python.  If you use "all" you'll *only* get results with C# *and* python.